# Writing a list of complex objects to CSV file using CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csv, dynamic, csvhelper, expandoobject

I have a list of class objects, which in turn contain a list of another class objects. They look like this:

```
public class Column
{
    public string ColName { get; set; }
    public List<Item> ItemList { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

They have two important properties:

1. The `Length` of `List<Item> ItemList` in all columns will be the same. I won't know what that length is until run-time though.
2. The actual values of `TimeStamp` in each column will be the same. In other words, the `TimeStamp` list in each column will be identical.

If you look at the following mock function that I wrote to create a list of `Column` objects you'll get a clear picture. This is an accurate description of what my actual data (which I get from somewhere else in the program) will look like:

```
private static List<Column> GetColumns()
{
    var dt1 = DateTime.Now;
    var dt2 = dt1.AddSeconds(1);
    var dt3 = dt2.AddSeconds(1);
    var dt4 = dt3.AddSeconds(1);

    var col1 = new Column()
    {
        ColName = "ABC",
        ItemList = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt1, Value = 1 },
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt2, Value = 2 },
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt3, Value = 3 },
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt4, Value = 4 }
        }
    };

    var col2 = new Column()
    {
        ColName = "XYZ",
        ItemList = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt1, Value = 4 },
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt2, Value = 3 },
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt3, Value = 2 },
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt4, Value = 1 }
        }
    };

    var col3 = new Column()
    {
        ColName = "KLM",
        ItemList = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt1, Value = 1 },
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt2, Value = 2 },
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt3, Value = 4 },
            new Item() { TimeStamp = dt4, Value = 8 }
        }
    };

    var list = new List<Column>
    {
        col1,
        col2,
        col3,
    };

    return list;
}
```

An important note is that I will not know the length of `List<Column>` until run-time, nor will I know the length of `ItemList` inside them until run-time. Furthermore, I will not know the names of each column until run-time. Now my goal is to write this information into a `CSV` file, of the following format.

[image]

I feel like `dynamic` is the way to go here, so I started with this:

```
var columns = GetColumns();

var timeStamps = columns.First().ItemList.Select(x => x.TimeStamp).ToList();

var writeList = new List<dynamic>();
for (int i = 0; i < timeStamps.Count; i++)
{
    dynamic csvItem = new ExpandoObject();
    csvItem.TimeStamp = timeStamps[i];
    // How to get columns?
    writeList.Add(csvItem);
}

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("output.csv"))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(writeList);
    }
}
```

This is a start, but since I don't know the number of columns I will have and the names of them, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Is using `dynamic` not an option here?

Alternatively I could forgo using `CSVHelper` at all, and write something from scratch like the following, but it's a bit messy. I'm iterating through the column list twice, and three loops in total. I'm looking for a more elegant solution, if possible.

```
var columns = GetColumns();

var timeStamps = columns.First().ItemList.Select(x => x.TimeStamp).ToList();

var headers = "TimeStamp";
foreach (var col in columns)
{
    headers += "," + col.ColName;
}

using (var fs = new FileStream("output.csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(headers);
        for (int i = 0; i < timeStamps.Count; i++)
        {
            var line = timeStamps[i].ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            foreach (var col in columns)
            {
                line += "," + col.ItemList[i].Value;
            }
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not create the whole csv structure using a `StringBuilder` and the save it as csv? It will be much faster than the 2nd method. As for csvHelper, I wouldn't even bother adding a nuget dependency for something simple like this.

Comment: @KosalaW do you have a sample for me to get started? My reason for using `CSVHelper` is that our project already uses it elsewhere for a lot of other CSV operations, so I wanted to stick with it.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the best you can do with CsvHelper for your requirements.

```cs
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("output.csv"))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        var columns = GetColumns();

        // Write header
        csv.WriteField("TimeStamp");

        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            csv.WriteField(column.ColName);
        }

        csv.NextRecord();

        // Write rows
        for (int i = 0; i < columns[0].ItemList.Count; i++)
        {
            csv.WriteField(columns[0].ItemList[i].TimeStamp.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));

            foreach (var column in columns)
            {
                csv.WriteField(column.ItemList[i].Value);
            }

            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes it does the job but also it's almost identical to my second code sample; I was wondering if there's a way around having to use something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using `dynamic`.

```cs
var columns = GetColumns();

var writeList = new List<dynamic>();

for (int i = 0; i < columns[0].ItemList.Count; i++)
{
    var csvItem = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;

    csvItem.Add("TimeStamp", columns[0].ItemList[i].TimeStamp.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));

    foreach (var column in columns)
    {
        csvItem.Add(column.ColName, column.ItemList[i].Value);
    }

    writeList.Add(csvItem);
}

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("output.csv"))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(writeList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to handle CSV writing using a StringBuilder. This code is suitable for situations where you just need to convert your object to csv. But If you need to use csv as a persistence mechanism (which is crazy anyway, use mongoDb or Sqlite instead), you will have to add more functionality to these extension methods.

**Delimiter**: The file type is CSV - Comma Separated Values. So this code uses ",". You can create TAB delimited too if you want by doing some simple modifications to this code.

Usage:

```
var columns = GetColumns();

Console.WriteLine(columns.ToCsv());
//OR
columns.SaveAsCsv(@"c:\columns.csv");
```

Csv Extensions;

```
public static class ColumnExtensions
{
    public static void SaveAsCsv(this List<Column> columns, string filePath)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(columns.ToCsv(), filePath);
    }

    public static string ToCsv(this List<Column> columns)
    {
        var csv = new StringBuilder();

        // Write as an expression or simply 
        //csv.AppendCsvHeader(nameof(Item.TimeStamp));
        csv.AppendCsvHeader<string, DateTime>(x => columns.First().ItemList.First().TimeStamp);

        for (var index = 0; index < columns.Count; index++)
        {
            var column = columns[index];

            // Most csv readers don't care if you have a "," at the end of the line. But for completeness we avoid doing that.
            // It makes the code a bit more complicated though. You can ignore this you want.
            csv.AppendCsvHeader(column.ColName, index == columns.Count - 1);
        }

        csv.AppendLine();

        for (var i = 0; i < columns[0].ItemList.Count; i++)
        {
            csv.AppendCsvField(columns[0]
                .ItemList[i]
                .TimeStamp.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));

            for (var index = 0; index < columns.Count; index++)
            {
                var column = columns[index];

                csv.AppendCsvField(column.ItemList[i]
                        .Value.ToString("N"), index == columns.Count - 1);
            }

            csv.AppendLine();
        }

        return csv.ToString();
    }
}

public static class CsvExtensions
{
    private const string Delimiter = ",";

    private static string AsCsvFriendly(this string val)
    {
        return val?.Replace(",", ";") ?? string.Empty;
    }

    private static string AddDelimiterIfRequired(bool withoutDelimiter)
    {
        return withoutDelimiter ? string.Empty : Delimiter;
    }

    public static void AppendCsvField(this StringBuilder stringBuilder, string value, bool withoutDelimiter = false)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append($"{value.AsCsvFriendly()}{AddDelimiterIfRequired(withoutDelimiter)}");
    }

    public static void AppendCsvHeader(this StringBuilder stringBuilder, string value, bool withoutDelimiter = false)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append($"{value.AsCsvFriendly()}{AddDelimiterIfRequired(withoutDelimiter)}");
    }

    public static void AppendCsvHeader<TIn, TOut>(this StringBuilder stringBuilder, Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> f, bool withoutDelimiter = false)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append($"{(f.Body as MemberExpression)?.Member.Name}{AddDelimiterIfRequired(withoutDelimiter)}");
    }
}
```